# Rewrite general form of ellipse to standard form (what happened in step 3?)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, geometry, conic-sections

From my math book  (Rewriting general form to standard from)

General form:

1. $$8y+4y^{2}-18x+9x^{2}=23$$
2. $$-18x+9x^2 +8y+4y^2 =23$$

What happened from step 2 to 3?

3. $$9(x-1)^2 -9+4(y+1)^2 -4=23$$
4. $$ 9(x-1)^2 +4(y+1)^2 =36$$
5. $$\frac{(x-1)^2}{4}+\frac{(y+1)^2}{9}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard form of an ellipse (and hyperbola) has terms of the form $\tfrac{(x-x_0)^2}{a^2}$ and $\tfrac{(y-x_0)^2}{b^2}$, so you'll want to rewrite "in that direction"; this is sometimes called [***completing the square***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square).

> 2. $$\color{blue}{-18x+9x^2} +8y+4y^2 =23$$
>
> What happened from step 2 to 3?
>
> 3. $$\color{green}{9(x-1)^2 -9}+4(y+1)^2 -4=23$$

Note that by expanding:
$$\begin{align}
\color{green}{9\left(x-1\right)^2 -9} 
& =9\left(x^2-2x+1\right)-9 \\
& =9x^2-18x+9-9 \\
& =\color{blue}{9x^2-18x}
\end{align}$$

But then backwards! Maybe you can now figure it out for the terms in $y$?

Comment: I got a much better idea now but I am still confused, which mainly stems from the fact that I am not very confident in **completing the square** - I am going to watch some khan a. videos on it.

Comment: There's more explanation and a lot of examples over [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square).

Comment: Here is a wonderful explanation from Eddie Woo. https://youtu.be/McDdEw_Fb5E

Comment: @JohnJoy Thank you so much that was wonderful video! Now my understanding is even better, I swear the god I had the same reaction as those kids in the video :D  - Now it also makes intuitive sense!